# doctest doesn't test classes methods in a module

Tags: python, doctest

I can't manage to have doctest test my modules classes methods.

My module looks like that:

```
simplemod
├── A.py
└── __init__.py
```

`A.py` contains:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        """This is a test

        >>> True
        False
        """
        pass
```

(so the tests should fail)

`__init__.py` contains

```
from .A import A

__test__ = {'A': A}
```

And then I run

```
>>> import doctest, simplemod
>>> doctest.testmod(simplemod)
TestResults(failed=0, attempted=0)
```

Why doesn't doctest test `A.method` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why.

### Why it doesn't work

doctest tries to detect which tests don't belong to the tested module, and doesn't run them. This prevents running all the tests of your dependencies.

Here, my doctest belongs to `simplemod.A` while I am testing `simplemod`.

### Recommended solution

From [the doctest documentation about testing complex packages](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#unittest-api).

Rename `A.py` to `a.py`, and replace `__init__.py`, with

```
from . import a

def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    import unittest
    import doctest
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(a))
    return tests
```

You can then run your test with a simple

`$ python -m unittest`

in the parent folder.